# How to ignore mypy errors when using NamedTuples with default values

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple, mypy

I have been able to have `mypy` do a type check on `NamedTuple` and use default values for `NamedTuple`.

However, I always have an error raised by `mypy` when I use default value.

Here is my code (I use Python 3.6)

```
class TestResult(NamedTuple):
    """To store results of a given Test Case"""

    outcome: str
    duration: Optional[int]  # in seconds
    comment: Optional[str]
    msg: Optional[str]


TestResult.__new__.__defaults__ = (None,) * 3  # type: ignore  # Hack for Python < 3.7
```

When I do `passed_tc = TestResult("Passed")`, I have the following error message

> error:Too few arguments for "TestResult"

Anyone got an idea on how to tell `mypy` we can have optional arguments and avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the values that need default values with the desired default values. For example:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Optional

class Test(NamedTuple):
    foo: str
    bar: Optional[str] = None
    qux: int = 100

t = Test("foo")
```

I've tested that this works at runtime for both Python 3.6 and 3.7, and confirmed it type-checks as expected using mypy 0.641.

Comment: Nice, it's usually the simplest thing that you never think of.